# How can I bake emission?

Tags: materials, texture-baking, baking, emission

I followed these steps : I created an image texture with a 4k image and the alpha disabled, I set the bake type to emit, then I selected the image texture and the object that had the emissive material and pressed bake, But all I got was a black image, am I doing something wrong?

Picture of the object having the emission node attached.

[image]

The same object when the baked image is attached

[image]

Comment: You have to use the Selected to Active option. The active is the last selected (yellow). https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html#selected-to-active

Comment: I selected the object that had the emissive material and pressed bake, it said that there were no valid objects selected , so I selected another object and then I selected the eyes and mouth (they were the active object) , but when I baked it the image was still completely black

Comment: You should select the eyes first, then the object, and the texture node (the 4k image) must be in the object's shader graph.

Comment: The texture node is supposed to be in the Shader graph of the eyes and mouth correct?

Comment: You want to create a texture, which fits to the other object not to the eyes. So the other object must contains the image.

Comment: The other object (The robot) has multiple materials assigned to it, Does it matter in which material I place the image texture?

Comment: create the Image Texture in the material that you've assigned to the eye

Comment: I tried doing that but i still got a plain black image